# SQL Trigger: On update of primary key, how to determine which "deleted" record cooresponds to which "inserted" record?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, triggers

Assume that I know that updating a primary key is bad.

There are other questions which imply that the `inserted` and `updated` table records match by position (the first of one matches the first of the other.)  Is this a fact or coincidence?

Is there anything that could join the two tables together when the primary key changes on an update?

Comment: I think you mean the [`inserted` and `deleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300(v=SQL.90).aspx) pseudo tables.  As to your question, if you have to update the primary key on more than one row at a time, you are asking for trouble trying to join these pseudo tables inside the trigger.  Just updating one row's primary key at a time poses no problem, right?

Comment: I assume I wouldn't be able to limit how many rows the trigger handles at once, so updating one at a time poses no problem, but no way to restrict updates to one at a time.

Comment: A trigger can certainly prevent an UPDATE that involves *changing* the primary key when more than one row is updated.  Is your application designed to change the primary keys on more than one row at a time?

Comment: "updating a primary key is bad" (a) There are lots of things that are generally bad, but which may be necessary in some circumstances. Or at least, which are less bad than alternatives. (b) Even if something is unquestionably bad, a given programmer may be forced to do it because he didn't make the design decision.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is **no** match of inserted+deleted virtual table row positions.

And no, you can't match rows

Some options:

- there is another unique unchanging (for that update) key to link rows
- limit to single row actions.
- use a stored procedure with the OUTPUT clause to capture before and after keys
- INSTEAD OF trigger with OUTPUT clause (TBH not sure if you can do this)
- disallow primary key updates (added after comment)

Comment: +1 Especially the part about row positions. This is the same kind of myth that leads people to believe `SELECT` without `ORDER BY` will always behave the same way.

Comment: I guess I could join both `inserted` and `updated` on primary key and only allow updates that don't modify primary key.  (I am using an `instead of` trigger.)

Comment: +1 for disallow primary key updates, if that's an option for your situation.

Comment: @Aaron -- but SELECT without ORDER BY does always behave the same way: unpredictably.

Comment: I ended up using an identity field which matched the before and after.  I figured it's fairly taboo to update an identity field.

Comment: @Dr.Zim - Not just taboo. SQL Server won't allow you to do so. Columns with the `IDENTITY` property are immutable.

Comment: @MartinSmith: A primary key is not necessarily an `IDENTITY` as well. In the case where primary keys are either natural keys or are generated in some other way, it is perfectly possible (not advisable) to update the primary key

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis - I presume that `@Dr.Zim` is now going under the moniker Zachary Scott and my comment was in response to the previous one which explicitly says it is taboo to update an identity column.

Answer (score 2):

Each table is allowed to have one identity column.  Identity columns are not updateable; they are assigned a value when the records are inserted (or when the column is added), and they can never change.  If the primary key is updateable, it must not be an identity column.  So, either the table has another column which is an identity column, or you can add one to it.  There is no rule that says the identity column has to be the primary key.  Then in the trigger, rows in *inserted* and *updated* that have the same identity value are the same row, and you can support updating the primary key on multiple rows at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- create an "old_primary_key" field in the table you're updating, and populate it first.

Nothing you can do to match-up the inserted and deleted psuedo table record keys -- even if you store their data in a log table somewhere.

I guess alternatively, you could create a separate log table that tracked changes to primary keys (old and new).  This might be more useful than adding a field to the table you're updating as I suggested right at first, as it would allow you to track more than one change for a given record.  Just depends on your situation, I guess.

But that said -- before you do anything, please go find a chalk board and write this 100 times:

I know that updating a primary key is bad.
I know that updating a primary key is bad.
I know that updating a primary key is bad.
I know that updating a primary key is bad.
I know that updating a primary key is bad.
...

:-) (just kidding)