# Inserted and Deleted trigger about changeable primary key (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Suppose I have a table with one column (is primary key) and I have trigger on that table to log any changes. Now when update a row (primary key) in Deleted I have old primary value and in Inserted I have new primary value. In multiple row update how can I tied old value (in Deleted) to new value (in Inserted)?

e.g:

myTable with one column (also is primary key):

```
PK
---
1
2
```

Now I update 1 to 4 and 2 to 3

```
Deleted
-------
1
2

Inserted
--------
3
4
```

how can I log these changes in audit table that has three column: PK, old_value, new_value

```
Audit Table
-----------
PK | old_value | new_value
1  | 1         | 4
2  | 2         | 3
```

in oracle we have old and new value but in sql server no.

Comment: You might check out [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629283/sql-trigger-on-update-of-primary-key-how-to-determine-which-deleted-record-c).

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have row triggers and does not provide any kind of logical row identifier in the `inserted`, `deleted` tables that can be use to join on in lieu of PK so there is no way of doing this apart from the techniques in @gbn's answer in the linked question.

Comment: If you could change the way you look at a PK change. Log them as a delete and an insert.

Answer (score -1):

Use Cursor In Trigger To Log Changes:

```
Declare @AuditTable Table (PK Int, OldID int, [NewID] Int)
Declare @OldID Int,
        @NewID Int

Declare C1 Cursor For
Select ID
From Inserted

Declare C2 Cursor For
Select ID
From Deleted

Open C1
Open C2
Fetch Next From C1 Into @NewID
Fetch Next From C2 Into @OldID
While @@FETCH_STATUS=0 Begin
    Insert Into @AuditTable(PK, OldID, [NewID]) 
    Values (@OldID, @OldID, @NewID)

    Fetch Next From C1 Into @NewID
    Fetch Next From C2 Into @OldID
End
Close C1
Close C2
Deallocate C1
Deallocate C2

Select * FRom @AuditTable
```

Comment: The order of rows when doing a `SELECT` from the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables does **not** always correspond in the way you seem to be banking on.